# Wildfly 10.1.0.Final on Windows 10 hang on "Starting deployment" at least 2 minutes

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly

I am having a really annoying "problem" with Wildfly. I have been using it for at least two years now and I really don't know what could be the problem.

So I have a fresh Windows 10 64 bit install, and then I started working on my projects as well which was started earlier and there were no problem with the deploy time.

I just pulled my stuff from VCS and then when I started to deploy it with Wildfly (as well as with Maven's Wildfly plugin and as well as put the .war into the deployments folder) the server prints out "Starting deployment ..." and then hangs for two minutes!! Always two minutes then deploy the application. It happens with no one project, with at least three, on my other laptop which has Windows 7 everything works fine.

I did not want to create any issue ticket yet on JBoss JIRA but I would like to ask for some help or tip, which can cause this kind of anomaly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well it´s Wildfly (bugs inc.). I would recommend to create a ticket for that, because honestly that issue could have so many reasons and knowing Wildfly it´s probably one of those you don´t think about at first. I would guess it´s a caching problem though.

Comment: I tried it with at least three, but after my post I decided to download the wildfly quickstart repo and then try it out. With one EJB project it works well, deploy goes as a new Lambo. I tried to log the wildfly with trace to get some more information but nothing special came. Wildfly maven plugin was in debug too but no more information. Wildfly memory settings are upgraded to 1 GB, but no luck. I am going to write out a ticket, but it is a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

So, yeah.

Windows 10 just got it again. I don't really like this OS, but I was curious about that.

So the problem was caused by the Windows Defender, my friend payed me attention about that. When the Maven build runs or the DEPLOY the Defender goes on 20-30% CPU time. When we switched off the Real time defending the problem went, and the deploy time (as on Windows 7 or anything) went to 20-30 sec. I just can not beleive that Windows 10 killed my working time for at least 1 month :D

Ubuntu here I come.